# How can I losslessly propagate a subprocess' exit code as my own program's exit code

Tags: rust, subprocess

[`std::process::ExitStatus`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.ExitStatus.html) doesn't guarantee to provide an [exit code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.ExitStatus.html#method.code), such as if the subprocess terminates due to a signal. I know I can get a signal via [`std::os::unix::process`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/process/trait.ExitStatusExt.html), but `signal()` may similarly return `None`.

If I want my Rust process to exit with the exact same status as the subprocess, how can I do so? I think the raw code use to construct the `ExitStatus` is the value I want, so I imagine if there was a `get_raw() -> i32` I could use that like `std::process::exit(status.get_raw())`, but no such method exists. The examples in the documentation seem to lose information.

Comment: The type can't express it, but by construction you will always have either a non-`None` `code` or a non-`None` `signal`: the former is returned when the process is found to have exited normally and the other the reverse, as determined by calling `WIFEXITED`. So this is a case where you could probably just `st.code().or(st.signal()).expect("a finished process has either exit or been terminated")`.

Comment: @Masklinn thanks for that insight, it wasn't clear to me even from the [libc docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Process-Completion-Status.html) that one of `WIFEXITED` or `WIFSIGNALED` would always return non-zero (for a terminated process).

Answer (score 2):

If the subprocess terminates due to a signal (e.g. when being killed or segfaulting) there will not be an exit code, `ExitStatus::code()` will return `None` in this case. So you just can not exit "with the exact same exit code" in this case.

The pragmatic solution is to invent an exit code which your program exits with for the case that the child was terminated via signal.

Comment: I understand that the process didn't exit per se, but it _does_ still terminate and [propagate a code to the parent](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Process-Completion-Status.html), that's how `ExitStatus` is [instantiated](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/process/trait.ExitStatusExt.html#tymethod.from_raw). My intent is to transparently proxy the subprocess' status to the caller, as if my Rust process wasn't in the middle.

Comment: If the child process was terminated due to an unhandled signal, the caller does not get a normal exit code. As you can see from the [Linux manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitid) you can extract the exit code of the child process via the `WIFEXITSTATUS` macro only if the child process terminated normally (`WIFEXITED` is true). The wait() functions works similar. If now another process is waiting for your process it can again get the information if your process has exited normally or due to an unhandled signal.

Comment: So if you really wanted to behave exactly like a the child process you would have to segfault if the child process segfaults or send yourself an unhandled SIGTERM or SIGKILL if the child process is terminated due to SIGTERM or SIGKILL.